# When I check for input, it always gives a negative response, why is that?

Tags: php, html, sql, post, is-empty

I made a system where I can input data, and show it in a table. I also made a check for the input (empty or not) but now my data doesnt get stored anymore. What can I do to fix this? Ive tried alot, a link to a different question with the answer would be good as well. Here is my code:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['vtprof']))
{
    if (empty($_POST["tun"])) {
        echo ('<br>Er zijn velden leeg');
    } elseif (empty($_POST["tpw"])) {
        echo ('<br>Er zijn velden leeg');
    } elseif (empty($_POST["tnm"])) {
        echo ('<br>Er zijn velden leeg');
    } elseif (empty($_POST["tbs"])) {
        echo ('<br>Er zijn velden leeg');
    } elseif (empty($_POST["tpl"])) {
        echo ('<br>Er zijn velden leeg');
    } elseif (empty($_POST["tps"])) {
        echo ('<br>Er zijn velden leeg');
    } elseif (empty($_POST["tgd"])) {
        echo ('<br>Er zijn velden leeg');
    } elseif (empty($_POST["tbd"])) {
        echo ('<br>Er zijn velden leeg');
    } else {
        $v_username = $_POST['tun'];
        $v_password = $_POST['tpw'];
        $v_name = $_POST['tnm'];
        $v_basis = $_POST['tbs'];
        $v_positie = $_POST['tps'];
        $v_plaatsing = $_POST['tpl'];
        $v_geboortedatum = $_POST['tgd'];
        $v_startdatum = $_POST['tsd'];
        $query = "INSERT INTO users 
                    VALUES (0, '$v_username', '$v_password', 
                            '$v_name', '$v_geboortedatum', '$v_startdatum', 
                            '$v_basis', '$v_positie', '$v_plaatsing')";
        $stm = $con->prepare($query);
        if ($stm->execute()) { 
            header("location:editprofiles.php");
        } else {
            echo ('Aanmaken mislukt');
        }
```

Comment: You should read about SQL injections, your code is insecure. In the same time, what is "negative response"? P.S. You also forgot at least two `}` in the end of your sample.

Comment: Your script is wide open to [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)
Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)
Use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) in either the `MYSQLI_` or `PDO` API's

Comment: There is no purpose in `preparing` a query that has no bindable parameter!

Comment: What is the output from this script?

Comment: Are you using `mysqli_` or `PDO`

Comment: This looks like it may well be a TYPO as you dont validate `$_POST['tsd']` but you use it in `$v_startdatum = $_POST['tsd'];` But as you dont show us a full [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) we cannot be sure, and you are not replying to comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have a Typo by checking your $_POST variables.

you check for

```
elseif (empty($_POST["tbd"]))
```

but want to get

```
$v_startdatum = $_POST['tsd'];
```

So the ckecking can't be true.

But please consider the advices in the comments.

Comment: So its a typo and the question should be closed as such. TYPO's are rarely any use to others so we normally just place a helpful comment and close the question